# Unity. Проблема с заполнением массива

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Написал код, который должен заполнять стринговый массив с клавиатуры через поле ввода.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Question;   // Сцена с полем ввода
    public GameObject Answer;     // Сцена с введённым текстом

    public InputField PoleVvoda; // Поле ввода

    public Text ShowText;    // Выводимый текст
    
    public string[] QuestionsArray = new string[20];  // Стринговый массив

    public void Confirm ()
    {
        Question.SetActive(false);     // Выключает сцену с полем ввода
        Answer.SetActive(true);        // Включает сцену с введённым текстом
        ShowText.text = PoleVvoda.text + ("?");     // Добавляет к введённому тексту знак вопроса
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)         // Массив состоящий из 20 элементов
        {
            QuestionsArray[i] = ShowText.text;     // Должен присваивать каждому элементу свое слово
        }
        PoleVvoda.text = string.Empty;  // Очистка строки ввода 
    }
```

Запускаю приложение, ввожу слово, а он присваивает введённое слово ***всем элементам***.

[image: Пример введенного слова]

Когда присваиваю через код, все отображается нормально, а через клавиатуру - никак.

Как сделать так, чтобы было поочередное присваивание? Если, что не бейте D:

Comment: Ам, вы берете строку и циклом запихиваете ее во все элементы массива. В чем тогда вопрос ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы берете одну строку и циклом вставляете ее во все элементы массива, в этом и проблема.
Я полагаю вам нужно что то такое. После каждого нажатия происходит одна вставка в массив, _curIndexQuestionsArray это текущий индекс для массива. Я предусмотрел элементарную защиту от переполнения _curIndexQuestionsArray, через его обнуление. Вам возможно это нужно реализовать как то по другому.

```
    private int _curIndexQuestionsArray;
    public string[] QuestionsArray = new string[20];  // Стринговый массив

    public void Confirm ()
    {
        Question.SetActive(false);     // Выключает сцену с полем ввода
        Answer.SetActive(true);        // Включает сцену с введённым текстом
        ShowText.text = PoleVvoda.text + ("?");     // Добавляет к введённому тексту знак вопроса
        if(_curIndexQuestionsArray >= QuestionsArray.Length)
            _curIndexQuestionsArray = 0;
        QuestionsArray[_curIndexQuestionsArray] = ShowText.text;   
        _curIndexQuestionsArray++; 
        PoleVvoda.text = string.Empty;  // Очистка строки ввода 
    }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу или другие справочные материалы про массивы в C#, не знаю что выбирать.

Comment: @Albert у вас же под рукой интернет, что вам еще надо ?) [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php) или  [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0) и еще куча ресурсов...